# When to build the Stone Quarry in Goblin Camp?

Tags: goblin-camp

For those that play Goblin Camp in its early stages (build 0.11) when do you guys put up the Stone Quarry?  Right away?  Wait until you have a certain number of orcs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait until you have the resources to wall it off so you don't get ambushed.

The best way to do that is to create an "Ant Lock" For example:

```
--------+-------
|              |
|---+----------|
| Quarry goes  |
| in here      |
----------------
```

With the "+" being doors.  This allows your goblins to come and go, without letting the ants out to rampage around your base, since they can't open doors.  Once you are attacked by ants, you can send in an orc squad to mop them up.

I usually wait until I've got at least 15 or so orcs, which I then make 2 squads of 5 and use the rest for labor.  Take care of just about everything else before you open up a new door for bad stuff to get you.

Comment: holy crap awesome answer!!

Comment: Glad to help, good to find more people playing an awesome game!