# How does the Stock Manager work in Goblin Camp

Tags: goblin-camp

How exactly does this menu work?  I think the number above the number between the '-' and '+' is what I currently have, but what does the other number mean?

Comment: omg another one of these games... I'm screwed.

Comment: This one has mouse capabilities and is going to be more macro focused.  I dunno if that is good or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...

So each item in the stock manager looks something like this:

```
  ,Flour
     1
[-]  5  [+]
```

- `,` This is the character that represents the material
- `Flour` Is the name of the resource
- `1` (The top) is the current number of that resource in your stockpiles.  If it's just laying around the map, it doesn't count
- `5` (The bottom) is the number you want your camp to have stocked, the orcs and goblins will automatically schedule jobs to fulfill this quota, items that have more than one requirement get a little more complicated in making that happen, but we'll get into that in a few.
- `[-]` and `[+]` These are buttons to decrease or increase your quota amount

That's the bare mechanics, but how it actually works can be a little trickier. (Just an aside, items don't appear listed in the SM until you can create them, the exception to this is `Bread` which you get at the start of the game, so until you can actually produce it changing it's quota in the SM won't do anything)

Let's start with a simple example.

You just start out, and you want to build a carpentry workshop, trying to do so will tell you that you don't have enough `logs` in your stockpile.  The next step is to build a stockpile and give it both it's catagory and the individual item you want it to hold (In our example that would be both `wood` and `log`).  You designate a block of trees and wait for the `logs` to start piling up.

But that never happens... Why?  Goblins are a lazy bunch by nature and only will do things if they're told to.  The quota set is 0, so they're done!  Not what we wanted.

Fire up the stock manager (SM) and hit the `+` a couple of times and the goblins will get to work.  Now if you use those `logs` (either for a carpentery workshop, wall or what have you), goblins will automatically fell designated trees to bring the total value of all `log` stockpiles up to your quota.  Now if for some reason they go over quota (You force them to fell trees, or in the case of `seeds`, you just have too many) then nothing will happen until you're back under.

So now you've got `logs`, simple huh?

Now for a more complicated example, which is where a little bit of a learning curve comes in.

You've got a fine camp going, but you want to really keep it safe, and those wooden clubs and bone daggers just ain't cutting it?  Time for stone weapons (v.11 or later).

Build your self a nice [Quarry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6493/2219) (Shameless plug I know).  Once it's up and running and secured from dreaded ants, time to start digging.  Open up the SM set your quota of `rough stone` and give it a stockpile to go into.

Now rough stone is pretty useless on it's own, so you need to turn it into something useful.  Build a stone carver, which will unlock a new option in SM, `sharpened stone`

Give yourself a quota and a stockpile for them and you're set to start building.  To make advanced weapons, you need a weapon crafter, which will give you the option to build stone weapons.  Since we're building stone axes, we'll need the following:

- 1 `wood plank`
- 1 `sharpened stone`

Make sure you have some in your stockpiles, and once you set a quota you'll start to build stone axes. (If you want your military orcs to actually use them, make sure you have a squad set up to use slashing weapons, if you already do, tell them to rearm from the military menu)

And there you have it, if you've survived up to stone axes, you're on your way to a well oiled machine of a camp.

That is until the Bees come for you...

Comment: Wow couldn't have asked for a better explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: sooo... much... detail.  +1 for the last line too.

Comment: This game is slowly killing me... way more fun than Dwarf Fortress IMO.